MongoDB - ExpressJS document automatically deleted 1 hour after it is created
I'm trying a make a simple backend application. When I register an user, It will automatically delete after 1 hour. But If i don't use createdAt or timestamps, The created user won't be deleted. I don't even have any controller that delete users. I only post register controller request.
My expecting is I want to it shouldn't be deleted after user created with using createdAt or timestamps. How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance
Github Repository
User Model Schema:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter a name"]
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: [6, "Please enter a password with min length 6"],
    required: [true, "Please enter a password"],
    select: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter an email"],
    unique: true,
    match: [
      /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/,
      "Please provide a valid email"
    ]
  },
  createdAt: {  //If I use createdAt the file will be delete after 1 hour
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  resetPasswordToken: {
    type: String
  },
  resetPasswordExpire: {
    type: Date
  },
  profileImage: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: "user",
    enum: ["user", "admin"]
  }
},
//{timestamps: true} // even If I use this, same thing will happen
);

//* UserSchema Methods
UserSchema.methods.generateJwtFromUser = function () {
  const { ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET } = process.env;
  const payload = {
    id: this._id,
    name: this.name
  };

  const token = jwt.sign(payload, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
    expiresIn:  "10m"
  });
  return token;
};

UserSchema.methods.getResetPasswordTokenFromUser = function () {
  const randomHexString = crypto.randomBytes(15).toString("hex");
  const resetPasswordToken = crypto
    .createHash("SHA256")
    .update(randomHexString)
    .digest("hex");

  this.resetPasswordToken = resetPasswordToken;
  this.resetPasswordExpire = Date.now() + parseInt("3600000");

  return resetPasswordToken;
};

//* Pre Hooks
UserSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) next(err);
      this.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

register controller:
const register = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;

  const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (existingUser) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ success: false, message: "This user already exists" });
  }

  if (!validateUserInput(email, password)) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ success: false, message: "Please check your inputs" });
  }
  const newUser = await User.create({ email, name, password });

  generateAccessToken(newUser, res);
});

const generateAccessToken = (user,res) => {
  const token = user.generateJwtFromUser();
  
  return res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("access_token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + parseInt(process.env.JWT_COOKIE) * 1000 * 60), // env = "10"
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true
    })
    .json({
      success: true,
      access_token: token,
      data: {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      }
    });
};


Check if you have some TTL index set.
